# Order DataFrame columns by multiple regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I want to order a DataFrame by multiple regex. That is to say, for example in this DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [20, 30],
                    'Col2': [50, 60],
                    'Pol2': [50, 60]})
```

get the columns beginning with P before the ones beginning with C.

I've discovered that you can filter with one regex like

```
df.filter(regex = "P*")
```

but I can't do that with more levels.

**UPDATE:**
I want to do that in one instruction, I'm already able to use a list of regex and concatenate the columns in another DataFrame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need list of DataFrames filtered by regexes in list with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
reg = ['^P','^C']
df1 = pd.concat([df.filter(regex = r) for r in reg], axis=1)
print (df1)
   Pol2  Col1  Col2
0    50    20    50
1    60    30    60
```

Comment: Look at the update I made few seconds ago. Thank you anyway

Comment: @Angelo - Not sure if understand `but I can't do that with more levels.` Can you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

you can just re-order columns by regular assignment.

export the colums to a sorted list, and index by it.

try:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [20, 30],
                   'Pol2': [50, 60],
                    'Col2': [50, 60],
                    })

df = df[sorted(df.columns.to_list(), key=lambda col: col.startswith("P"), reverse=True)]

print(df)
```

Comment: note: if you need a more complex regex, you can modify the `key` to your needs